# UIButton is moving... it should not be moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uibutton, ios7

I have a .xib with two UIButtons right next to each other.

[image]

When I start up the app, everything looks fine. Once I push play, the audio starts, the button turns to pause, and everybody is happy.

If I push stop, the play button moves to the left, and leaves a trail of dots...
[image]

In iOS 6, this was not an issue.

Does anyone know why this might be happening??

Comment: Is this app built against iOS7 SDK or iOS6 SDK?

Comment: Not sure exactly...?  the Deployment target is iOS 6.1

Comment: I'm pretty sure those blue dots are the exact color of UIView's default tintColor in iOS7

Comment: Put differently, what version of Xcode are you using? 4.6 or 5.0?

Comment: 5.0   I still don't understand what built against means haha

Comment: If you were using 4.6, your app would be built against iOS6.1 SDK and your issue would be related to the many small 6.1 SDK defects in iOS7.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like at some point a title of '...' is being added to that Play button.  That's just a guess, but the default layout for a button is to have the image on the left and the title on the right.

Comment: Both buttons use the "Default Title" in the inspector. If I double click on the buttons in Xcode, its clear there is no text or title. After comparing both buttons via the inspector, the image filename seems to be the only difference.

Comment: So, there is no title at design time, but a title could easily be set at runtime.  Look at the action handler for the Stop Button since thats when the problem seems to present itself.

Comment: By event handler you mean the UIAction method triggered by the button? I read through, there's nothing changing any labels or text... Besides, that would've been an issue regardless of the iOS version I'm running

Comment: @DanMoore Buttons can have different titles for different states.  Change "State Config" to "Highlighted" and see if your title is "Highlighted Title" (also gray).

Comment: Yup, they are all gray... That also would not have changed since iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

There is a few things you can do.
First, clear all constraints in window like below...
Second... Check all the states of your button (interface and code), see if you didn't add a title '...' to your button in the active state or the enabled and disabled state.

here is the picture update to see it clearer...
[image]

Comment: I've seen those button items before in Xcode 5!! However, for some reason, they aren't showing themselves in my .xib window, not even in my mainStoryboard window. Is there a toggle somewhere to make that menu bar appear? Also, all the button states have blank "default" titles.

Comment: hmm. I would try to work around without the menu bar or maybe you will have to subclass it

Comment: subclass it?? I just want to clear all constraints... But I can't find what your picture illustrates.

Comment: oohh. lol sorry. On storyboard (or xib file), click the window. it should work. Go to standart Editor (1 window only) to see it clear. It should be on bottom right corner

Comment: ohh it wasn't showing up because I wasn't using autolayout!!! But that means there are no constraints to remove anyway haha

Comment: im glad it worked. i hate getting stuck with such simple things too.... they're annoying